# magento 2 checkout page is keep loading, it wont let us checkout.

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

when we are trying to checkout the circle is keep moving, it don't let us checkout. We have also cleared the cache files on the chrome.[image]

Comment: check in console and ajax response for error.

Comment: Have you check console and log file of magento?

Comment: If you are a developer then please check browser log and Network tag for ajax error and issue... There must be a js error which stop the page to load further and loaded keep running.

Comment: How do I check that? Thanks

Comment: Press F12 and refresh the browser and check console tab of the window comes under after press F12

Comment: Hi Ashish, I am getting long list of error, could you please try from your end, as here it is not allowing me to send long list of errors. Website is www.officialphonerepair.co.uk , thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue. Sometimes after modifying any .js file in magento cache related to JS are not cleared correctly. So we need to clear it through the terminal... Please run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

If you made any change from the admin panel to the configurations setting, like the customer account or other setting, you need to clean the cache or if it is asked, reindex as well.

This can be down directly from System > Tools > Cache management or
if you have access to the filesystem and your website, you can try to run this commands:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

and if a reindex is required:

```
php bin/magento index:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

As usual Magento checkout page is the most overloaded with JS, that is why it is so slow. There are also other issues that influence load time:

- complex network code
- extra price rules
- useless shipping and payment methods etc.

Here is the guide that will help you cope with all these difficulties:
https://onilab.com/blog/magento-checkout-slow-fix-it-in-8-simple-steps/